# TYPO3 8 EXT: newsletter massmail slow

Tags: performance, newsletter, typo3-8.x

I've a Problem. I created a Newsletter System based on TYPO3 8 + [EXT:Newsletter](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/newsletter/) and my customer sends like 4 Newsletter Pages with attachments every week (about 20000+ Recipients).

The problem is that it's really slow. I've set the interval to 50 Newsletter per Minute and at the beginning of the send task...it's all okay. It sends like 40 - 50 Newsletter per minute, but after some time it goes down...

Here's a little statistic for yesterday:

- 16:21 - 17:21 o'clock 933 sent
- 17:21 - 18:21 o'clock 749 sent
- 18:21 - 19:21 o'clock 605 sent

And now it's at 250 in 1hour...by the way the customer is sending through his own SMTP (Domainfactory).

Do you have any idea? And yea the extension uses swiftmailer from TYPO3 8 core to send out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a shared hosting plan? What you describe sounds like your SMTP account gets throttled because you hit some limits defined by your provider. Check Domain Factory's tos at: https://www.df.eu/de/agb/

> Bei Shared-Hosting-Produkten ist es dem Kunden untersagt, über den Webserver mittels Skripten massenhaft E-Mails [...] zu versenden.

It states that you are not allowed to send mass mails from their shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a perfomance issue with sending emails through `ext:newsletter` es well. In my case it was due to the preperation of the links in the newsletter with activated `ext:realurl`. As soon as I disabled ext:realurl, the emails where sent very fast.

Hope, this helps!